# Unable to save remote photo to camera roll in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to save a remote photo (stored in Firebase Storage) to camera roll, but the following code does not run as expected in Swift:

```
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
    if let photoUrl = URL(string: "<see below for the url of the image>") {
        PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromImage(atFileURL: photoUrl)
    }
}, completionHandler: { (success, error) -> Void in
    if let err = error {
        print(err)
    }
})
```

URL of image:

> https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/nearbie-ee55a.appspot.com/o/wallpaper_pictures%2F52YgRFw4jWhYL5ulK11slBv7e583_E6A1D795-ED73-4C1E-98E1-CC97FF87E4C1?alt=media&token=0b090de3-43ab-426a-b63b-9d61372732d0

The print statement prints:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=-1 "(null)"
```

**Why does this happen and how do I resolve it?**

**Edit - This is the correct answer**

Download the image first then save it to camera roll

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(
    with: photoUrl,
    completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let imageData = data {
            PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: UIImage(data: imageData)!)
            }, completionHandler: { (success, error) -> Void in
                if let err = error {
                    print(err)
                }
            })
        }
    }
).resume()
```

Comment: You should download the image to the device and then save it to the Camera roll

Comment: Thank you @Alexander, I've tried but no luck, see updated the question. Did I do it wrong?

Comment: For one, you do not seem to actually be kicking off the dataTask, you are only creating the task, you need to start it using resume()

I recommend reading the docs for whichever API you use in code.

Comment: @Alexander, Oh yes, you're right! Problem Solved. If you post your answer below, I will accept it. Unless you don't care about reputation

Comment: @KrisGellci, I thought you were Alexander, anyway, problem solved, thank you. If you post your answer below, i will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should download the image to the device and then save it to the Camera roll

Comment: To people who want to see the code, go to the edit part of the question, that's the correct answer suggested by @Alexander